# How to show custom events on symfony debug

Tags: php, symfony, debugging, events

I was trying to debug an event, and found [this documentation from symfony](http://symfony.com/doc/current/event_dispatcher.html#debugging-event-listeners), however all the events that are shown are:

```
console.command
console.terminate
fos_elastica.post_transform
kernel.controller
kernel.exception
kernel.finish_request
kernel.request
kernel.response
kernel.terminate
kernel.view
security.interactive_login
```

None of the custom events show up, plus, we're defining the.
But I see that besides the kernel, FOS is there also.

I've got my listener registered in the following way:

```
company.domain.listener.service_pro_listener:
   class: Company\Domain\Listener\Customer\CustomerListener
   arguments:
     - '@company.command.executor'
   tags:
     - name: werkspot.domain.synchronized_event_listener
       event: 'Company\Domain\Event\Customer\RegisteredEvent'
       method: 'onRegisterPushToSalesforce'
```

The event is working, manual testing on the website I could validate that everything is working as expected. Still it would have been much easier if I could simply confirm that everything were setup correctly through that command. So there must be a way show our events in command list.

Is there anyway to achieve this?

Comment: I would start with debugging this particular command - from where is it taking events for example and why yours aren't there.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you're using a custom event dispatcher (I see that by the tag on your listener service definition), while Symfony `bin/console debug:event-dispatcher` command will display the listeners of its own dispatcher.

So to do what you want, you will have to implement your own command to debug your own dispatcher, or change the dispatcher used to use the one from Symfony.

Comment: Thats a bummer.

Comment: Yes ^^ But if your dispatcher implements the `Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcherInterface`, you should be able to do your own command pretty easily by extending the `Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Command\EventDispatcherDebugCommand`, just change the command name and the service called in the `EventDispatcherDebugCommand::getEventDispatcher()` method.

Comment: Why have your own event dispatcher as a matter of fact?

Comment: @Gerry the fact of event dispatcher being in house is that we got all code decoupled from Symfony, which means also to make our own dispatcher.